# How to use RS Scripter for moving reports from one server to another?

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have followed every guide i have found on the web but none have worked fully. I got the program to connect to the ssrs server to display all the reports. I also got the script to generate for a report i was wanting to move. The script fails to find the .rss file in the directory in which the program generates it to.

Goal: Transfer reports + subscriptions from Server A to Server B
Note: The folder structure on the servers are not the same.(No clue how/where to define this path) The folder for the scripts is the default, c:\tempreports and the rs.exe is on my local machine.

When i run the batch file, it errors saying it cannot find the .rss file at the path. The path should be c:\tempreports\reportpathonserver\report.rss

I looked the log.txt and it has the correct path of the file so no idea what i am doing wrong. Can someone please help me setup this type of transfer?

Comment: I've tried a similar approach in the past and given up.  IMO it's too fiddly and there are too many moving parts.  I approach this challenge using multiple Deployment Configurations in Visual Studio. This doesn't solve the subscriptions challenge but I just do those manually.

Comment: The bad part is there is no support forum or anything. A few guides but even the guides are different and don't explain enough about the types of transfers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after hours of searching and playing around with settings. To transfer a report to a new server with a different folder structure. You have to use the Create new parent folder option. This allows you to tell where the report needs to be put. Currently, I'm working on solving the subscription error I'm getting, saying the password can not be empty. I'm not exactly sure which password it's referring to but I assume it's the password for the subscription itself(seems obvious) but with the lack of resources on this software...don't assume anything. If anyone has encountered this error or have an idea of how to fix it please don't be shy! I'd rather not spend hours more solving a password conflict on something so simple.

I was able to solve this. Since the entire SSRS server structure changed from old to the new, i had to change a few things in the generated files to make it work. One was to handle different datasources for the subscriptions. Had to update the `<reference></reference>` tags in the `createsubscription` methods to point to the new DS. After a lot of trial and error i finally got it working. hope this information helps anyone else.

Comment: Well i was correct, the password needed what the subscription password. Still doesn't work yet, now it says the code of the .rdl file is wrong hahahah this software just isnt worth the trouble.